# Laravel - Extend relationship with orderBy not working properly

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have this code:

```
$query = $platform->challenges();
// return response()->json($query);
$challenges = $query->orderBy('start_date', 'DESC')->get();
return response()->json($challenges);
```

As you can see, I get the challenges relationship query builder and I am trying to order the results by the date. If I uncomment second line I get 2 items array. But If I add the orderBy to the builder I only get 1 item array.

Is there something I am missing?

**EDIT**

Model code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use GeneaLabs\LaravelModelCaching\Traits\Cachable;

class Platform extends Model
{
    use Cachable;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'connection_key', 'code', 'enabled'];

    public function brands()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Brand');
    }

    public function challenges()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Challenge');
    }
}
```

Maybe is the cachable trait making the bad behavior here?

Comment: can you share your whole code here?

Comment: That is the whole controller method code... or you want the model too?

Comment: would you mind, pls?

Comment: yes @LordVermiis share your model code as well...

Comment: I just added the model code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (using fetched collections):

```
$challenges = $platform->challenges->sortByDesc('start_date');
return response()->json($challenges);
```

Or this (with query builder):

```
$platform->disableCache(); 
$challenges = $platform->challenges()->orderBy('start_date')->get();
```

**FROM THE DOCS**:

**Manual Flushing of Specific Model**

You can flush the cache of a specific model using the following artisan command:

`php artisan modelCache:clear --model=App\Model`

This comes in handy when manually making updates to the database. You could also trigger this after making updates to the database from sources outside your Laravel app.

Comment: This works, for sure, but It has a problem. It adds a index to every item in the array `["0": {...}, "1": {...}]`. Spite it works, I am trying to understand why the query builder don't works properly, your solution works with the final collection and array sorting.

Comment: If you suspect being the Cache system, start by disabling it for that specific query: `$challenges = $platform->disableCache()->challenges()->orderBy('start_date', 'DESC')->get();`.

Comment: You right, I just did, and it works as well. Maybe I have to flush cache before this API calls.

Comment: `Call to undefined method GeneaLabs\LaravelModelCaching\CachedBuilder::challenges()`

Comment: This is the code, add it to your response `$platform->disableCache();
        $query = $platform->challenges();
        $challenges = $query->orderBy('start_date')->get();`

Comment: Added to the answer ;)

Comment: There is no need to chat, it is finished and it works, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
$query = $platform->challenges();
$challenges = $query->orderBy('start_date', 'DESC')->get();
return json_encode($challenges);
```

Comment: I dont see any difference with my code, just the response type. But I will try.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a column named "start_date", if not why not do something like this

```
$challenges = $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

since you have the created_at column already